# Django: preventing QuerySet deletions on a model?

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I have a model whose delete() method I have overridden.  Because this is not called on a bulk QuerySet delete, I would like to disable QuerySet deletion or somehow assert against it happening.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom `QuerySet` class and use it in a manager, e.g.:

```
from django.db import models

class NoDeleteQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("can't delete this queryset")

class NoDeleteQuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return NoDeleteQuerySet(self.model)

class MyModel(model.Model):
    objects = NoDeleteQuerySetManager()
```